# Hardware “back” button doesn't work after typing in edittext

Tags: android

in my form fragment Hardware "back" button work not correctly. For example when I opened fragment and when I didn't start typing, and I pressed Hardware "back" button it's work excellent. But when I started typing and after typing press to Hardware "back" button not working.

my form fragment i am using OnResume() method use to handle back button process.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {

    super.onResume();

    getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    getView().requestFocus();
    getView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
                //getView().clearFocus();

                getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();


                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: so your code ...

Comment: Can you please post your code.. Would be more easy to help..

Comment: you can use onbackpressed event

Comment: what code have you tried?

Comment: Does it close your keyboard instead of your desired behaviour?

Comment: I handle the back button press in fragment oResume()

Answer (score 0):

Override `onBackPressed()`

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
   moveTaskToBack(true);
}
```

Comment: public void onResume() {

    super.onResume();

    getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    getView().requestFocus();
    getView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){

                getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();


                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
}

Comment: Edit your question post this code into your question

Comment: i am handling back button onResume() method

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText  creditcatno= (EditText)view.findviewByid(R.id.ed1);
```

public void onResume() {     super.onResume();      creditcatno1.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {         @Override         public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {               // call previous Fragment here               return true;            }             return false;         }     });           getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);     getView().requestFocus();     getView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {         @Override         public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {             if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {                 // handle back button's click listener                 //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Back press", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                 getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();                 return true;             }             return false;         }     });  }

Answer (score 0):

Make a static string variable:

```
public static String currentFragment = "";
```

When openning the fragment set this variable value as your fragment name:

```
MainActivity.currentFragment = "your fragment name";
```

Now in the `onbackpress` method which is in the `MainActivity`:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(currentFragment.equals("your fragment name"){
      // your onbackpress code for fragment
    }else{
         super.onBackPressed();
    }

}
```